# Count(*) MySQL - Need to display how many entities have a count of 4 or higher

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

I have a linking table in MySQL which has the id's of people in one column and the id's of media that they have appeared in.

I have run a query:

```
SELECT person_id,COUNT(*)
FROM person_media      
GROUP BY person_id;
```

This has returned:

```
person_id   COUNT(*)
1           7
2           4
3           9
4           5
5           9
6           12
7           12
8           3
9           1
10          8
11          8
12          9
13          3
14          1
15          4
16          3
17          3
18          1
19          8
20          1
21          4
```

What I am looking to do is to count how many people have a COUNT(*) of 4 or more.  I can't seem to find a way to do it, but I know it has to be possible.  I'm relatively new to MySQL, so be gentle :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `HAVING`

```
SELECT person_id,COUNT(*)
FROM person_media      
GROUP BY person_id
HAVING COUNT(*)>=4
```

Answer (score 0):

The inner query gets all those with a count of 4 and more.
The outer query counts how many that are:

```
select count(*) 
from
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM person_media      
  GROUP BY person_id
  HAVING count(*) >= 4
) tmp
```